# return separate queries for conditional logic postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to check if a field in the table is null and return separate results/perform a different query if it is.  This is the general high-level logic, but I can't figure out how to run this in Postgres.

```
CASE
  WHEN (select master_user_id from users where id = 88 IS NULL) THEN
    select company_name from users where id = 88;
  ELSE
    select company_name from users where id = (select master_user_id from users where id = 88);
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the logic as below if there is a record for id =88 always but master_user_id is null:

```
select company_name from users 
where id IN (select COALESCE(master_user_id,id) from users where id = 88 )
```

if you are checking for existence of record id = 88 then :

```
select company_name from users 
where id IN COALESCE((select master_user_id from users where id = 88),88)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  How would you do this to return multiple query results.  i.e. using an IN for the id

select company_name from users 
where id =  select COALESCE(master_user_id,id) from users where id = 88 )

Comment: yes , if the subqury returns multiple records you should use `in` ,